# Symfony2 Form entity field with query_builder

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, query-builder

I have a form with an entity field, without the query_builder work fine, but with the query_builder the form display the result of the query but is not valid when is submited.

```
//tecnicosType
$builder->add('dt', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MSKLigaBundle:Jugadores',
    'label' => 'DT',
    'query_builder' => function(
    \MSK\LigaBundle\Entity\JugadoresRepository $er) use($equipoId){
        return $er->getJugadores($equipoId);
    },
    'property' => 'nombreCompleto',
    'empty_value' => "Sin definir",
    'required' => false
    ))
```

And the function is

```
public function getJugadoresQueryBuilder($equipo)
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('j');
    return $queryBuilder->select('j')
        ->where('j.equipo_id = :equipo')
        ->setParameter('equipo', $equipo);
}
```

when the form is submited return

```
array
'dt' => 
array
  0 => string 'This value is not valid.'
```

If i coment the query_builder the form validate fine.
I can't find the solution, thank for any help.

Comment: Does the `MSKLigaBundle:Jugadores` entity have some validation markup? (Annotation) Or the form has any validation? Please paste some relevant code.

Comment: no, they don't have any validation.

Comment: where does that `$equipoId` come from? How and where is that declared?

Comment: this is a property of the equiposTecnicosType (this form)
And is setted by the function "setEquipo".
    $equipoId = $this->getEquipo();

Comment: thank you Debreczeni, the problem is $equipoId, this value is passed the first time but no the second. 
    
    `$equipoTecnicos = new equipoTecnicosType();
 $equipoTecnicos->setEquipo($equipo->getId());

 $formTecnicos = $this->createForm($equipoTecnicos, $tecnicos);`

Comment: Are you able to resolve this problem then?

Comment: Yes, thank you! i pass again the value $equipo and now it's working.